# Removing items from a TileList Flex actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5

How to remove only one item in my Tile List ?

I did this...

```
tileList.dataProvider.removeAll();
```

but I want to remove one specific item...not all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `removeItemAt()`:

```
var i = 2; // or whatever indexed item you actually need to remove
tileList.dataProvider.removeItemAt(i);
```